# Wufoo Integration using HTML code

Tags: jquery, html, wufoo

I am taking the html/css of the form created in wufoo form(not Iframe or script). I have added the redirect url of the same page where i have embeded the form. How can i print the message on success as it is plain HTML page. And Form is redirecting to wufoo page in case of errors. I want validation on  the same page only.

Comment: You have two options : 

1. submit the form via [the wufoo API](http://help.wufoo.com/articles/en_US/SurveyMonkeyArticleType/Wufoo-REST-API-V3)

2. Perform validation client-side using something like [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)